# A JavaScript alert or dialog with a TextArea instead of TextField

Tags: javascript

var msg = prompt("Type something:") is very useful but it uses a TextField. I would like to have a TextArea instead, so the user can type and see a bigger message. Is it rocket science? Probably not but google did not help. I wish I was a front end guy. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: This is the solution: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a prompt, instead use a textarea in a div.  There are tons of ways to do this. ;)

If you use something like [thickbox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/) and jquery you can put the textarea in a "popup" window that the user can enter text into.

Comment: +1 karlw.  I'm used to using thickbox, but jQueryui would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting a pop up type feeling for this then use a lightbox effect. You can simulate a pop up by using this method and still insert a textarea instead of just using a textfield. You can use something like [this.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&&sa=X&ei=SdI7TICxLZLmsQOp3u3aCg&ved=0CCIQBSgA&q=javascript+lightbox&spell=1&fp=d4ae37bcc0eae736)

Answer (score 0):

according to google, there is hope ;)

http://javascript.about.com/library/blmodald1.htm

I think you want the prompt method...

Comment: I start my question stating that prompt is what I don't want because it has a TextField. :-)

Comment: ahh -- sorry.  Then yeah, i think you are going to have to do what Andir said and use jquery to throw up a window with something in it...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible out of the box with JavaScript. If you want to do something like that I'd recommend using Ajax to show an HTML/CSS-driven form. It's admittedly more complicated but also way more flexible.